# Pyside6, Designer - как убрать границу снизу окна

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyside6, qstatusbar

С помощью `StyleSheet` добавил картинку в качестве бэкграунда, подогнал размер окна под размер этой картинки. Но появилась некая граница с куском изображения(помечено красным).

Вопрос - как убрать эту границу?

[image: пикча]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это `statusbar` - удалите его если он вам не нужен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: помогло, спасибо. А есть возможность оставить статус бар на будущее, просто дав ему инструкцию игнорировать область картинки?

Comment: @Булат пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Возможность всегда есть. Задайте новый вопрос. приведите ваш пример и расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.